# How do I create a JFrame that is always on top only when it is focused?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a JFrame that is on top of all other windows - including the taskbar - when it is focused, but not when another window is focused. Ideally, something like this would work:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FullHeightWindow extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

    public FullHeightWindow() {
        super("FullHeightWindow");
        setSize(100, 10000);
        addFocusListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.paramString());
        setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FullHeightWindow());
    }

}
```

However, the call to `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` triggers another `focusGained`, which sets the window back to always on top. (This is on Windows 10, if it matters.)

Using the Windows API, you have to use the `SWP_NOACTIVATE` flag to keep this from happening: `SetWindowPos(h, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE)`. It turns out that doing exactly that in JNA will work. But is there a portable way to do something like this in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other events like this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class FullHeightWindow extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    public FullHeightWindow() {
        super("FullHeightWindow");
        setSize(100, 10000);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FullHeightWindow());
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Putting `true` in `mouseClicked` and `false` in `focusLost` is the closest to what I want. It doesn't work when you alt-tab into the window instead of clicking, though.